Why is this folder duplicated in `sysfs`?
I have a Raspberry Pi that is running the 'bookworm' version of the OS; the 64-bit version of the OS if that makes any difference. I've installed one of the SHT3X temperature & humidity sensors, and it is apparently working fine. It's connected via I2C interface (channel 0, /dev/i2c-0 I believe). I can read temp & humidity from the files in sysfs; I believe the sensor is working correctly.
I have found that there are two identical folders in sysfs that contain the same output and control files for the SHT3X device:
folder 1: /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 device -> ../../../0-0044
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 heater_enable
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_alarm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_max_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_min
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_min_hyst
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 name
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 of_node -> ../../../../../../../../firmware/devicetree/base/soc/i2c@7e205000/sht3x@44
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 repeatability
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../class/hwmon
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_alarm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_max_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_min
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_min_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:52 uevent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 update_interval

folder 2: /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 device -> ../../../0-0044
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 heater_enable
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_alarm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_max_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_min
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 humidity1_min_hyst
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 name
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 of_node -> ../../../../../../../../firmware/devicetree/base/soc/i2c@7e205000/sht3x@44
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 repeatability
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun  2 21:55 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../class/hwmon
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_alarm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_max
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_max_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_min
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 temp1_min_hyst
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:52 uevent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 update_interval

And there's more; e.g.:
folder 3: /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2/subsystem/hwmon2
I realize there are symlinks involved, but is there a true/immutable location for these files in sysfs?  I've read some references on sysfs 1, 2, but found no explanation for this apparent duplication. Can someone explain the apparent redundancy, and if there is an immutable location for the files?

/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2 is a symlink to /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2 (technically, /../../devices/platform/soc/3f205000.i2c/i2c-0/0-0044/hwmon/hwmon2).
/sys/devices contains the sysfs files, by device, for all the devices in the system. This allows them to have a unique path and name based on their “location” (as a platform device, a PCI device etc.).
/sys/class gives access to a subset of those files, by class. This allows them to be found by purpose (vaguely defined). For example, a program interested in all hardware monitors can look at everything under /sys/class/hwmon. Because this is only a different view of the “devices” hierarchy (or a subset thereof), the “class” tree consists mostly of symlinks pointing into the “devices” tree.

So if I'm writing a script to read (e.g. humidity1_input), does it make any difference which of these folders I use? I ask because the longer folder name has changed at least once.

Both folders can vary based on enumeration changes (the first one on the I²C bus at least, the second one among all hardware monitors), so you need to handle changes there anyway. In theory, looking at /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon?/name should let you find the right hwmon directory. Since the hwmon entry is a symlink to the devices entry, both paths are equivalent.

Could you explain what constitutes enumeration changes... i.e. would this be the result of moving the sensor to a different i2c bus (e.g. i2c1)?  My concern is simply that the script I've written to read the sensor values must know where the file to be read is located.  Or should I be using another method to read the sensor data?

Anything that changes the order of enumeration: it could be changing to a different bus (but that shouldn’t happen without hardware changes), but even variations in device initialisation time can cause the order to change. Your script really should be designed to handle changing locations; like I said above, looking at the name entry should allow the right monitor to be identified.

I’m referring to this, from the ls ouput: -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun  2 21:55 name. If you read that you’ll get the device’s name; with that information you should be able to determine if it’s the device you’re interested in.

Oh yes, sorry - cat name => sht3x.  So, are you saying I should just verify that name==sht3x, and if it does then I have the correct sysfs folder?

Yes, that’s what I’m saying (assuming there’s a single sht3x device).
